# How to keep clock on at night on charger

Tags: settings, screen, clock

I keep my phone on a wireless charger beside my bed. Until recently, the clock would show on there very dimly with a black background, plus some other notifications and stuff. Recently, it changed to where it just goes fully black. I didn't knowingly change anything. This was not an app, just something native to Android. I'm on version 12, Pixel 3. Any idea how I can get the clock back?

It shows for a while then goes away, like some time in the night. I'm not sure if it's a time out thing, or maybe something that happens when charge goes to 100%.  Or maybe specific to being within the bedtime mode window, although I've scoured those settings.

BTW, this most obvious setting is enabled: Settings->Display->Lock screen->Always show time and info

Comment: "*the clock would show on there very dimly with a black background*" this looks like a screen saver. Could you check on Settings - Display - Screen saver?

Comment: It looks pretty much like this:  https://www.sammobile.com/2018/07/17/good-lock-2018-always-on-display  I don't think it's a screen save per se.